# How can I split my screen in 3 using tmux from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

I'm writing a bash script that splits the screen in 3 and runs a command on each pane.

I basically want to run the bash script and the bash script is supposed to split my screen in 3, and run top in a pane, htop in the other pane and a perl re.pl in the third pane for example

any help or pointers are apprecieted!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The direct way to do this is to create a detached session, create the panes, *then* attach to the session.

```
# -d says not to attach to the session yet. top runs in the first
# window
tmux new-session -d top
# In the most recently created session, split the (only) window
# and run htop in the new pane
tmux split-window -v htop
# Split the new pane and run perl
tmux split-pane -v perl re.pl
# Make all three panes the same size (currently, the first pane
# is 50% of the window, and the two new panes are 25% each).
tmux select-layout even-vertical
# Now attach to the window
tmux attach-session
```

You can also do this in one call to tmux, but there probably is no reason to do this from a script:

```
tmux new-session -d top \; split-window -v htop \; split-window -v perl re.pl \; select-layout even-vertical \; attach-session
```

Comment: split-pane is not available in the docs for 2.3, for some reason http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/tmux.1.html#contenttoc6 although tmux doesn't complain when split-pane is actually used

Comment: Hm. I couldn't say when or why it was removed,  but it looks like `split-window -t <pane>` is the replacement. (Come to think of it, separate `split-window` and `split-pane` commands seems redundant; you never actually split a window, since all windows contain at least one pane.)

Comment: You can do that from inside tmux. Make three panes (2x`C-b "`) and then enter command-mode with `C-b :` and type `select-layout even-vertical` (or `even-horizontal`, I find that more useful)

Comment: The question is specifically about writing a script to do this, without manual intervention that `C-b "` would require.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, and this helped me when I had this wish during interactive use.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/) for this. It lets you define windows and panes per window in a configuration file that you can then use with:

```
tmuxinator start <some-name>
```

It is really neat!

(I am sure it is possible to do this with pure bash also.)